# Android - How to loop images in ListView

Tags: android

How can I make the images on a scrollable list loop? 
Like I have a horizontal list and i want the images will loop instead of stopping at the end of the list.

[image]

Like this one. This how i did my list..

```
        <com.custom.view.HorizontalListBounceView
            android:id="@+id/hscrollview"
            android:paddingLeft="70dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scrollbars="none" >

            then my imageviews. . . .

        </com.custom.view.HorizontalListBounceView>
```

The HorizontalListBounceView extends to HorizontalScrollView. Im not really using adapters for now. But if necessary I can change it. 
What are ways on looping my images?

Thank you for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a custom adapter with an infinite item count and overriden method `getView` which takes `position % realItemCount`s item and fill a view with it?

Comment: @sftdev `position % realItemCount` is wrong - realItemCount is more than actual element count in the loop